# catch notes like animation

Tags: android, list, animation

I need to create an animation like in the "Catch notes" app.  The animation that I am referring to is when you press on an object in a list, all of the object above it go up and all of the objects below it go down, all with animation.

I was thinking that it could not be possible by using a regular list view. so maybe the way to do it is just to put the objects manually one by one in some way?

Any better ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all visible items (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() to getLastVisiblePosition()) and get there views with listView.getChildAt(index). 
Then you can animate all the views above and below your view with ObjectAnimator or similar.

Example:

```
for (int i = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i < myListAdapter.getCount() && i <=    listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {
  View v = listView.getChildAt(i - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
  ListItem listItem = myListAdapter.getListItem(i);
  if (v != null) {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", 0, -screenHeight).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added a short example that should animate all views upwards.